# Cost Based Optimizer and impossible queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

The queries in the SQL below are valid queries but because of constraints on the table there can never be data in the table to match the where clause.

I ran **explain** on both queries in Postgres and it looks like the CBO isn't aware of this fact and intends to execute those queries.  I would have assumed that it would recognize that there can't be any data and not even try.

```
create table myTest ( a char(1) not null, b integer);
insert into myTest values ('A',1), ('B',2), ('C',3);
select * from myTest where A = ‘Texas’;
select * from myTest where A is null;
```

I have searched for information and I found a lot of deep information on how the CBO works but nothing about this.  I was expecting to see a CBO parameter that said something like "skip impossible queries".

I know different CBOs will work differently but, in general, do optimizers really not take this information into account?  If not, why not?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAMjNa7cC4X9YR-vAJS-jSYCajhRDvJQnN7m2sLH1wLh-_Z2bsw%40mail.gmail.com#CAMjNa7cC4X9YR-vAJS-jSYCajhRDvJQnN7m2sLH1wLh-_Z2bsw@mail.gmail.com

Comment: 1) a table without a PRIMARY KEY has no meaning 2) you  use the wrong kind of quotes. 3)The optimizer predicts zero retrieved rows, in both cases, even without a PK or optimize/vacuum.

Comment: Correction: initially, it expects 10 rows. After analyze it expects 1 for both queries  (probably 0, but rounded up for safety)

Answer (score 0):

That seems really unlikely.  Cost-based optimizers do pretty much what their name implies -- they use statistics on the table (or estimated statistics) to choose the best algorithms for running the query.

They make very limited use of constraints -- probably none, actually.  They may take unique constraints into account, but that is probably through the index rather than the constraint.

Why don't they do this?  I suppose the people writing database optimizers are trying to solve the "harder" problems.  If a single character is compared to `'Texas'` that is really something the query writer should know about.

Further, query plans can be cached.  Constraints can be removed.  In general, I don't think that adding or removing constraints invalidates cached query plans.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I have been doing database work for a long time and I have never seen this, precisely because it never occurred to me to write a nonsensical query :)  (Not that I haven't, just never intentionally)

Comment: sql server has contradiction detection that takes into account constraints.

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Cool.  Here is one blog post on the matter . . . http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2011/06/the-query-optimizer-and-contradiction-detection/.